# Ruby on Rails: Cannot allocate memory issues when application size is big

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I have a Linux 14.04 server setup with RAM: 2GB and Hard-drive: 40GB. (Digital Ocean)

And my Ruby on Rails application size is almost 10GB. (Because of some images stored, which is I think not good)

I am now always getting Memory allocation problems. I cannot not run any rake task that writes data to the database. And sometimes application also stops working.

Here is my server's hard drive details,

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        40G   16G   22G  42% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            991M  4.0K  991M   1% /dev
tmpfs           201M  364K  200M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           1001M     0 1001M   0% /run/shm
none            100M  4.0K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Is this memory allocation problem occurring because my Ruby on Rails application size is big?

If so, Is there any workaround to solve this issue as I have some more space available in hard drive?

Comment: that's not your server's memory details, it's your server's hard drive details.

Comment: @sevenseacat - yes that is correct. It would be good if you could help me with the problem?

Comment: the easiest solution would be to just increase the memory on your box.

Comment: don't put words in my mouth.

Comment: @sevenseacat - cool thanks